# Como eu poderia melhorar o código desse controle de paginação?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Montei um controle de paginação para uma blog que estou montando, mas não tenho certeza se o fiz da melhor maneira, tentei copiar o funcionamento do controle de paginação dos sites da Stack Exchange. Vocês poderiam dar uma olhada e me dizerem o que acham?

Uma *screenshot* de como ele ficou quando o total de páginas era igual a 10:

[image: controle de paginação]

O trecho do código da *view* referente ao controle de navegação (utilizei Bootstrap):

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
        @{ 
            var totalPages = Model.TotalPostsCount / Model.PostsPerPage;

            var urlPreviousPage = Url.Action("Page", new { arg = Model.CurrentPage - 1, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage });
            var urlNextPage = Url.Action("Page", new { arg = Model.CurrentPage + 1, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage });
        }

        @* Navigation button << *@
        <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == 1 ? "disabled" : null)">
            <a href="@(Model.CurrentPage != 1 ? urlPreviousPage : null)">
                <span>&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        @* Navigation button 1 *@
        <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == 1 ? "active" : null)"><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = 1, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage })">1</a></li>

        @* Navigation buttons from 2 to 5 *@
        @if (Model.CurrentPage >= 1 && Model.CurrentPage < 5)
        {
            for (int page = 2; page <= 5; page++)
            {
                if (totalPages >= page)
                {
                    var pageUrl = Url.Action("Page", new { arg = page, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage });

                    <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == page ? "active" : null)"><a href="@pageUrl">@page</a></li>
                }
            }
        }

        <li><a>...</a></li>

        @* Middle navigation buttons *@
        @if (Model.CurrentPage >= 5 && Model.CurrentPage <= totalPages - 4)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = Model.CurrentPage - 2 })">@(Model.CurrentPage - 2)</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = Model.CurrentPage - 1 })">@(Model.CurrentPage - 1)</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = Model.CurrentPage })">@(Model.CurrentPage)</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = Model.CurrentPage + 1 })">@(Model.CurrentPage + 1)</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = Model.CurrentPage + 2 })">@(Model.CurrentPage + 2)</a></li>
            <li><a>...</a></li>
        }

        @* Navigation buttons from (totalPages - 4) to (totalPages) *@
        @if (Model.CurrentPage > totalPages - 4)
        {
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = totalPages - 4, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage })">@(totalPages - 4)</a></li>
            <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == totalPages - 3 ? "active" : null)"><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = totalPages - 3, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage })">@(totalPages - 3)</a></li>
            <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == totalPages - 2 ? "active" : null)"><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = totalPages - 2, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage })">@(totalPages - 2)</a></li>
            <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == totalPages - 1 ? "active" : null)"><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = totalPages - 1, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage })">@(totalPages - 1)</a></li>
        }

        <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == totalPages ? "active" : null)"><a href="@Url.Action("Page", new { arg = totalPages, postsPerPage = Model.PostsPerPage })">@totalPages</a></li>

        @* >> *@
        <li class="@(Model.CurrentPage == totalPages ? "disabled" : null)">
            <a href="@(Model.CurrentPage != totalPages ? urlNextPage : null)">
                <span>&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

A *action* para vocês terem uma ideia do que está sendo enviado apara essa *view*:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Page(int arg = 1, int postsPerPage = 10)
{
    var sort = Builders<Post>.Sort.Descending(p => p.Created);

    var viewModel = new HomePageViewModel
    {
        CurrentPage = arg,
        PostsPerPage = postsPerPage,
        TotalPostsCount = await ZigBlogDb.Posts.CountAsync(_ => true),
        Posts = await ZigBlogDb.Posts.Find(_ => true).Sort(sort).Skip((arg - 1) * postsPerPage).Limit(postsPerPage).ToListAsync()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Parece legal o seu. Eu gosto desse aqui. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Hm... esse link me levou a descobrir que existe um helper para montar esse controle de paginação, não sabia disso. Acho que reinventei a roda se querer. xD

Comment: Ele é bem bacana. Até agora não encontrei nada que não daria para fazer com ele, até esse fds eu tive dificuldade de paginar retorno de procedure, mas ele tem uma classe para fazer isso que resolveu minha vida... de novo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, sinto te dizer, mas você reinventou a roda sim. [Há um componente que faz isso de uma forma mais performática](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList). [O pacote NuGet dele está aqui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/).

Vi que você está usando Entity Framework. Este componente PagedList.Mvc não suporta paginação assíncrona. Se quiser usar paginação assíncrona, instale também [este outro pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.EntityFramework/).

---

**EDIT**

Você comentou de usar MongoDB. [Também há paginação para o MongoDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoPagedList/).

Comment: Hehehe eu percebi isso, o foda é que perdi um bom tempo elaborando o algoritmo para montar esse pequeno controle de paginação. Bom, vou dar uma lida sobre esse PagedList e conferir também esse outro pacote que permite a paginação assíncrona. ~~E não estou utilizando Entity Framework (xD), estou utilizando o driver do Mongo DB para C# que já possui um ORM integrado, mas vou experimentar o pacote mesmo assim.~~ Hm gostei desse pacote de extensão do PagedList pra MongoDB, vlw mesmo Cigano!