# Dúvida com paginação em Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paginação

Alguém sabe como implementar uma paginação ou teria um exemplo usando está arquitetura  https://github.com/cleytonferrari/PadraoDeRepositorio/tree/master/TISelvagem
Gostaria de usar o Skip() e Take() do linq:

Como foi feito neste exemplo
[Paginação MVC asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23694/pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mvc-asp-net)

mais estou tendo um erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
public IEnumerable<Cliente> ListarPagina(int paginaAtual, int itensPorPagina)
{
    return contexto.Cliente.Skip((paginaAtual - 1) * itensPorPagina).Take(itensPorPagina).ToList();
}


public class ListaPaginada<T>
{
    public int TotalItens { get; private set; }
    public int ItensPorPagina { get; private set; }
    public int PaginaAtual { get; private set; }

    public int TotalPaginas
    {
        get { return Math.Ceil(TotalItens / ItensPorPagina); }
    }

    public List<T> Itens { get; private set; }

    public ListaPaginada(List<T> itens, int totalItens, int itensPorPagina, int paginaAtual)
    {
        this.Itens = itens;
        this.TotalItens = totalItens;
        this.ItensPorPagina = itensPorPagina;
        this.PaginaAtual = paginaAtual;
    }
}


public ListaPaginada<Cliente> ListarPagina(int paginaAtual, int itensPorPagina)
{
    var clientes = contexto.Cliente;
    var totalClientes = cliente.Count();
    var clientesDaPagina = cliente.Skip((paginaAtual - 1) * itensPorPagina).Take(itensPorPagina).ToList();

    return new ListaPaginada<Cliente> (clientesDaPagina, totalClientes, itensPorPagina, paginaAtual);
}
```

Comment: Esse eu não conheço, eu uso esse aqui, me atende 100%, tenho paginação de 400 mil registros. https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/

Comment: Eu gostaria de aprender a fazer é não usar coisas prontas, não que eu seja contra cada um usa o que achar melhor, mais eu gostaria de aprender a fazer

Comment: Então, coloca o que você já fez pra gente poder debater os problemas e dúvidas. A pergunta está bem vaga, na verdade não é difícil de fazer não, mas tudo vai depender das tecnologias q você escolheu

Comment: Pronto, está ai!

Answer (score 0):

Não sei dizer o porque ele usou o Math.ceil naquele código de reposta. Eu acredito que o que você quer é essa [classe (Math)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Math(v=vs.110).aspx) em C# que por sua vez tem o método [Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Math.ceil](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp) você vai achar no JavaScript.

No link do github que você postou ele usa Math.cel apenas no javascript dele (estou colocando isso na reposta para você ver que o funciona no Javascritp). Olha essa [classe](https://github.com/cleytonferrari/PadraoDeRepositorio/blob/b522dad6eca43ee69da4c17cc08f00350cdbb1d1/TISelvagem/TISelvagem.UI.Web/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js) dele.

Comment: Se possível eu gostaria de aprender a fazer isso sem precisar usar nada pronto, não é uma questão de inventar a roda, mais para mim evitar ao máximo usar coisas prontas pode evitar possíveis dores de cabeça com alterações.

Comment: Na verdade eu não botei nada pronto. rsrs, não usar o Math é reescrever o framework da microsoft

Comment: Eu acabei digitando errado mesmo. Era pra ser o `Math.Ceiling`. Já corrigi no exemplo. O arredondamento lá é para calcular o número de páginas total a ser exibido. Arredondo para cima com o `Ceiling` porque uma lista com 11 registros e paginação de 10 em 10 precisa ter 2 páginas. Se dividir 11 por 10 e não arredondar para cima vai ter apenas 1 página, que não é correto para o caso, porque teríamos que ter mais uma página apenas com um registro.

Comment: Bom que corrigiu o erro. Tem mais alguma dúvida? Se corrigiu o erro não deixa de marcar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma biblioteca que poderia te ajudar nisso, ela se chama [X.PagedList](https://github.com/ernado-x/X.PagedList/blob/master/README.md) e na página do projeto no GitHub você encontra alguns exemplos de utilização. [A biblioteca está disponível pelo NuGet também.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/X.PagedList/)

Pode ser que [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99783/como-eu-poderia-melhorar-o-c%c3%b3digo-desse-controle-de-pagina%c3%a7%c3%a3o) lhe ajude em alguma coisa, nela eu pedi uma revisão de código sobre um controle de paginação que montei manualmente.

Comment: Se possível eu gostaria de aprender a fazer isso sem precisar usar nada pronto, não é uma questão de inventar a roda, mais para mim evitar ao máximo usar coisas prontas pode evitar possíveis dores de cabeça com alterações.

Comment: @itasouza O ideal é você não reinventar a roda, mas se estiver procurando reinventar do mesmo jeito, da uma olhada na pergunta linkada na minha resposta, lá eu fiz um controle de paginação na mão.

Answer (score 0):

Após varias tentativas resolvi utilizar o Plugin PagedList, a resposta final ficou desta forma:

Agradeço a todos pelas contribuições, dentro da arquitetura que estou estudando, já conseguir fazer praticamente todos os métodos necessários, mais conto com a ajuda de todos para evolução.

```html
        //http://localhost:1608/api/ApiGuiaCidade/consulta/paginacao/1/4
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("consulta/paginacao/{pagina:int}/{pagsize:int}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ClientesPaginacao(int pagina,int pagsize)
        {
            try
            {
                int PageNumero = (pagina * 1);
                var tCliente = new ClienteAplicacao();
                var listarDeClientes = tCliente.ListarTodos();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listarDeClientes.ToPagedList(PageNumero, pagsize));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```